# Initializing chained hash table to NULL. Get "lvalue required as left operand of assignment" error. Why? Here is my code:

Tags: c++, hashtable

I am trying to create a chained hash table. I have started by building a dynamic array and am now trying to initialize each array pointer to NULL. But I get the error "lvalue required as left operand of assignment". Why? Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>         // for i/o functions

using namespace std;

const int HTSIZE = 997;     //size of the hash table

struct CHTNode
{
    int value;
    CHTNode *next;
};

void InitializeTable(CHTNode* &cHT);

int main()
{
    CHTNode *chainedHT;
    chainedHT = new(nothrow) CHTNode[HTSIZE];
    if (chainedHT == NULL)
    {
        cout << "ERROR: Memory allocation error"
             << endl;
        return 1;
    } //end if
    else
    {
        InitializeTable(chainedHT);
    }
}

void InitializeTable(CHTNode* &cHT)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < HTSIZE; i++)
        &cHT[i] = NULL;                     //ERROR FOR THIS LINE
}
```

Comment: You do not have an array of pointers. You have an array of objects of type CHTNode.

Comment: What do you think `&cHT[i]` means exactly?

Comment: Remove all unnecessary stuff. Then, reconsider whether this problem has anything to do with hash tables. Then, throw the error message at a websearch. Then, realize that this question is not that uncommon (hint: see the "related" section on the right) and finally delete it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have an array of pointers. You allocated an array of objects of type CHTNode.

You could value initialize this array when it was allocated. For example

```
chainedHT = new(nothrow) CHTNode[HTSIZE] {};
```

If you want to write a separate function that zero-injitialize each element of the array then the function could be declared like

```
void InitializeTable( CHTNode* cHT, int n );
```

and defined like

```
void InitializeTable( CHTNode* cHT, int n )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) cHT[i] = {};
}
```

As for erroneous statement

```
&cHT[i] = NULL;
```

then it does not make a sense. Expression `&cHT[i]` is a temporary object that you are try to assign.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your first statement clarifies allot. So how would I change the code to have an array of pointers of type CHTNode? I am trying to create a chained hash table and resolve collisions using separate chaining. This is just the start of course. HTSIZE is a constant for now, but later will be a variable that is prompted from the user.

Comment: @Joshelog The array will look like      CHTNode **chainedHT;
    chainedHT = new(nothrow) CHTNode *[HTSIZE];

Answer (score 1):

The address-of operator `&` returns the address of the given expression, so `&cHT[i]` evaluates to the *address of* the `i`th element of `cHT`. It *seems* you're trying to assign to the variable `cHT[i]`, but what you're doing right now is trying to assign to the address value of `cHT[i]`, which makes no more sense than trying to assign to a constant.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It shows me that my error must be when I declared the array. I am trying to create an array of pointers / build a chained hash table with separate chaining for collision resolution. I can see that my array is just an array of CHTnode type now. Thanks for clarifying.